# Greasemonkey with Youtube

Tags: javascript, youtube, greasemonkey

So, I decided that starting small with learning either Javascript or Greasemonkey one at a time was just not ambitious or efficient enough. So I decided to make a Greasemonkey script that alters the way Youtube works.

I'll start with problems I am pretty sure it isn't, I do have the HTML5 player enabled, and I double checked the names of the functions I am calling in the Youtube API. I am also pretty sure that I installed Greasemonkey correctly and that the script is loading correctly, based on the fact that when a Youtube page is open, the "YoutubeSpeed.user.js" file is in the Greasemonkey context menu with a check mark next to it, and that I tried installing a much simpler Greasemonkey script (http://www.wired.com/wired/archive/webmonkey/greasemonkey/helloworld.user.js) and it worked just fine. In case it isn't obvious, I am basically trying to have Youtube do a bunch of stuff as soon as a video is opened. (specifically, have it pause, set the speed to 2x, set the quality to 720p, and make sure the volume is at 100.

I think the problem is either with my use of the Youtube API, or my use of Javascipt syntax, or my use of Greasemonkey syntax. I really think these could all be useful tools going forward, so a little help learning them would be much appreciated. Also, any other ideas for improving the general Youtube experience to add to this script would be appreciated as well.

EDIT: Ah, it seems there was a mistype. I absolutely meant to include my script, and since it's pretty short, I hope you guys will be able to help me. Here it is in all it's glory.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        YoutubeSpeed
// @namespace   matt47721@yahoo.com
// @description Double The Speed Of Youtube Videos By Default
// @include     https://www.youtube.com/*
            function onPlayerReady() {
            target.player.pauseVideo();
            target.player.setPlaybackRate(2);
            target.player.setPlaybackQuality(hd720);
            target.player.unMute();
            target.player.setVolume(volume:100);
            };
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
```

As to an MCVE, for M, I have been unable to make any Greasemonkey script involving Youtube videos work. As for the C, the entirety of my script is there. And as for the V, I guess I could have described that a little better, my apologies. When I open a Youtube video, it does none of the things I am trying to accomplish with this script, it just plays normally. And since the question is about how to make my Greasemonkey script work with Youtube, and the only code I put in is the Greasemonkey script that is supposed to affect Youtube I would say I've eliminated things not relevant to the problem.

I hope this is satisfactory, I apologize for doing so poorly before, this is my first time using StackOverflow.

Cheers,
Eridine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, this question is way too broad and open ended.  Please read the [help/dont-ask].  In general, ask only specific, objective, questions -- one per post.  Either provide an MCVE or, in the case of Greasemonkey questions, the relevant parts of your userscript and a link to the target page.

Answer (score 0):

Your script references a variable "target.player" but you haven't linked that variable to the player on the youtube page.  You need to first find the player using something like:

```
var videoElement = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
```

which gives you a handle to the video player, only then can you manipulate the player using the API.  A complete, working, script can be found here:
https://github.com/mirnhoj/video-element-playbackrate-setter/